# Returning a list as IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my method i am expected to return an IEnumerable but i created a list within so i can add result to it and i wanted to return the created list with added items as an ienumerable but having trouble return the list as ienumerable. I tried to create an ienumerable so i can add items to it but it didn't allow me to add.

this is my method:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,User>> GetUser(int? id, int? pageNumber)
        {
            int _pageNum = pageNumber.HasValue ? pageNumber.Value : 1;
            var userIndex = new UserService().GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum).GroupBy(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 1));
            var userList = new List<User>();
            foreach (var group in userIndex)
            {
                string curLetter = group.Key;
                foreach (User user in group)
                {
                    userList.Add(user);
                }
            }
            return userList.AsEnumerable();
        }
```

Comment: I'm failing to see the point in anything you do after initializing `userIndex`.  Why are you creating a list or doing any of that?

Comment: @Servy in my foreach loop i getting names based on the first letter so for the letter A i am getting all users that start with A and looping through it and i am adding the results to a list so i can display the list - the names are already sorted its a matter of displaying in groups with the letter as a header and names following the header

Comment: So far you have different item type. List is "of User", IEnumerable is "of IGrouping<string, User>". Unless User implements IGrouping<string, User> your problem is not related to List nor IEnumerable.

Comment: @KendallFrey the problem is that since i created a list to add my items i would like to return the list results as ienumerable

Comment: @Masriyah That's not the problem, that's the expected result.

Comment: @KendallFrey - i could see that but i was wondering if casting would be a possibility

Comment: You say that you're going to return a sequence of `IGrouping<string, User>` elements, but you're actually trying to return a `List<User>`. It's not clear to me how you expected that to work. They're completely different types.

Comment: Have you tried with `new UserService().GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum).OrderBy(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 1));`

Comment: You can convert a List<T> to an IEnumerable<T> by calling the AsEnumerable() function on the list object. `var a = List<string>(); return a.AsEnumberable();`

Comment: @CraigM 1) That's not *converting* the list.  The list is already an `IEnumerable`, that's just casting it. 2) There's no need to even do that; `List<T>` is *implicitly* an `IEnumerable<T>` because it implements that interface.  You need to do all of thing to return the list, if the generic arguments are appropriate.

Comment: @Servy Pedantic semantics.

Answer (score 0):

For what i understand:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,User>> GetUser(int? id, int? pageNumber)
    {
        int _pageNum = pageNumber.HasValue ? pageNumber.Value : 1;
        return new UserService().GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum).OrderBy(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 1));
    }
```

Maybe i don't get your question.

@Servy has pointed the problem, why not just

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, User>> GetUser(int? id, int? pageNumber)
{
    int _pageNum = pageNumber.HasValue ? pageNumber.Value : 1;
    return new UserService().GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum).GroupBy(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 1));
}
```

Comment: this was my original code but i want to return results so: letter A would be a header followed by names that start with A thus i've created a foreach loop. The foreach loops show proper info its returning within the foreach loop is what is giving me trouble

Answer (score -2):

use ActionResult As return type of your Action 
and change 
return userList; to  return userList.tolist();